# Trouble Adding values in form using Javascript - My level = Rookie

Tags: javascript, html

I rarely use Javascript but occasionally use snippets of code to accomplish things in my web pages. I recently used some code to add values of Radio buttons, drop down lists and text boxes in a single form. The result updates the total at bottom when an option is selected and / or changed. However, this works in Chrome but not IE, Safari or FireFox. I'm pretty confident I've screwed up the function updatesum() calculations. I feel that there must be something simple that I am missing. I've even tried removing everything other than 2 options and simply adding them together yet it still doesn't work in IE, FF nor Safari.
Here is the javascript code for the page.

[Link to the page to check out](http://missionrealestateservices.com/test-proto.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function CurrencyFormatted(amount)
{
var i = parseFloat(amount);
if(isNaN(i)) { i = 0.00; }
var minus = '';
if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
i = Math.abs(i);
i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);
i = i / 100;
s = new String(i);
if(s.indexOf('.') < 0) { s += '.00'; }
if(s.indexOf('.') == (s.length - 2)) { s += '0'; }
s = minus + s;
return s;
}

function updatesum() {
 tot = 

(

(((document.form.sum1.value -0) + (document.form.sum2.value -0) +     (document.form.sum3.value -0) + (document.form.sum4.value -0) + (document.form.sum5.value -0) + (document.form.sum6.value -0) + (document.form.sum7.value -0) + (document.form.sum8.value -0) + (document.form.sum9.value -0) + (document.form.sum10.value -0) + (document.form.sum11.value -0) + (document.form.sum12.value -0)) - 
((document.form.sum1.value -0) + (document.form.sum2.value -0) + (document.form.sum3.value -0) + (document.form.sum4.value -0) + (document.form.sum5.value -0) + (document.form.sum6.value -0) + (document.form.sum7.value -0) + (document.form.sum8.value -0) + (document.form.sum9.value -0) + (document.form.sum10.value -0) + (document.form.sum11.value -0) + (document.form.sum12.value -0)) * ((document.form.sum15.value -0))) +
(((document.form.sum1.value -0) + (document.form.sum2.value -0) + (document.form.sum3.value -0) + (document.form.sum4.value -0) + (document.form.sum5.value -0) + (document.form.sum6.value -0) + (document.form.sum7.value -0) + (document.form.sum8.value -0) + (document.form.sum9.value -0) + (document.form.sum10.value -0) + (document.form.sum12.value -0)) * ((document.form.sum13.value -0))) + ((document.form.sum14.value -0))   

);

document.form.sum.value = CurrencyFormatted(tot);
}
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use document.form.name.value to get the radio checked value.

Try this:

```
function getOptionSelection(name) {
    // define function to get value of checked radio button using the name
    var fields = document.form[name];
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].checked) {
            return fields[i].value;
        }
    }

    // return 0 if nothing was checked
    return 0;
}

function updatesum() {
    // define array to store values
    var sums = [0];
    var i;

    // get values from radio buttons
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        sums[i] = +getOptionSelection('sum' + i); // <<<<<< it's simpler to convert string to numeric using the + sign
    }

    // get values from text input and select drop down
    for (i = 11; i <= 15; i++) {
        sums[i] = +document.form['sum' + i].value; // <<<<<< it's simpler to convert string to numeric using the + sign
    }

    // simplify the code by adding the two summary parts
    var part1 = sums[1] + sums[2] + sums[3] + sums[4] + sums[5] + sums[6] + sums[7] + sums[8] + sums[9] + sums[10] + sums[11] + sums[12];
    var part2 = sums[1] + sums[2] + sums[3] + sums[4] + sums[5] + sums[6] + sums[7] + sums[8] + sums[9] + sums[10] + sums[12];
    var tot = (part1 - part1 * sums[15]) + (part2 * sums[13]) + sums[14];

    document.form.sum.value = CurrencyFormatted(tot);
}
```

I noticed that you use the -0 to convert the values from string to numeric.  It's simpler to just put a + sign in front of the variable.

So:

```
var x = '5';
var y = x - 0;  // <<<< y = 5
var z = +x;  // <<<< z equals 5
```

Make sure there's no space between the + sign and the variable name.

Comment: I'd like to ask you one other question. How would I go about adding a comma in the currencyFormatted number? Right now, there isn't one in the number.

Comment: Try this function: toLocaleString()